# google app engine search API: works hardcoded but not with variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I have a document with a GeoField and a NumberField like this:

```
document = search.Document(doc_id=str(self.id),
                               fields=[search.GeoField(name='loc',value=search.GeoPoint(20.0, 30.0)),
                                       search.NumberField(name='maxradius', value=10)])
search.Index(name='Professional').put(document)
```

when i query:

```
query = "distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < 10"
```

I get the result correctly
but when I query:

```
query = "distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < maxradius"
```

I get `RuntimeError: ValueError('could not convert string to float: maxradius',)`

what's happenning ,any ideas ?

Comment: I suspect this can't be done in the current AppEngine search API. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings for documentation, though it doesn't explicitly address this.

I think you should use a large fixed maxradius (e.g. 100km / 100000m), then return the distance as a Field Expression specified in the QueryOptions, and then you have to manually filter the list using each individual maxradius.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options#Python_Writing_expressions

Answer (score 0):

The error raised indicates that maxradius is treated as a string and cannot be converted to a float as specified by the error message, Then as already mentioned, you need to set dynamically this variable. You can try this way, Note the single quotes instead of double quotes to inject dynamically :

```
query = 'distance(location, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < %d' % maxradius
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i mean , just like the location is different in every document , i need the maxradius to be different.

Comment: maxradius represents the max distance to fetch customers for a given buisness , each buisness can set it's own maxradius.

Answer (score -1):

what you want is this:

```
maxradius = 10
query = "distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < " + maxradius
```

edit:

try something like this (NOT EXACTLY LIKE THIS):

```
query = "distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < "
for i in range(10):
    do_something(query + i)
```

this will give you 10 different query strings. You can switch this up and make it loop through a list of predefined values such as:

```
maxradius = [1, 5, 23, 6, 2, 1, 77]
query = "distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < "
for i in maxradius:
    do_something(query + i)
```

This is how you can have a different max radius for each document

Comment: no, i want to have a different maxradius for each document. this is not good for me.

Comment: Well then you can adjust the `maxradius` variable in a simple for loop. The important bit here is having the original query as `“distance(loc, geopoint(20.0, 30.0)) < ”` and then adding the variable (which will be cast to a string)

Comment: I don't know what you want. You asked a question , and you now have two answers that work. Don't go complaining that we didn't answer your question. We both fixed the python runtime error. I suggest you look at some of [these](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks), so you can understand some basic programming ideas, then maybe re-ask a different question.

Comment: I am not complaining , i appreciate your time for answering. your suggestions do solve the error , but they fail to achieve the goal. if I wanted to have a constant injection to my query , i would not have bothered asking the question.

the idea of my project is to give businesses customers based on both's locations and *not* to give businesses customers that are too far away, so each business sets a maxradius of it's own. 

your suggestions give a solution of one maxradius for everyone.